# Rails Active Record Object being created for no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using Rails 7. I have the models Post, Venue and VenuePost models. They look as follows:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :venue_posts, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :venue_posts
end

class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :venue_posts, dependent: :destroy
end

class VenuePost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

Now, my Posts#new action looks as follows:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  Venue.all.each do |v|
    vp = @post.venue_posts.build(venue: v)
    v.venue_posts << vp
  end
end
```

The problem is that, even when I do not call the create action, the post is still being saved to the database and will show up on the index page. Why is that and how can I prevent it while still keeping the same behaviour I have right now, which is instantiating one VenuePost for each Venue when creating a new Post and being able to edit it in the form and save it.

Thanks for reading

**Edit for reference:**

*Strong parameters:*

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, venue_posts_attributes: [:id, :title, :content])
end
```

*Nested form:*

```
<%= form.fields_for :venue_posts do |vpf| %>
  <div>
      <strong>Venue:</strong>
      <%# vpf.object.venue.name %>
      <%= vpf.label :title, style: "display: block" %>
      <%= vpf.text_field :title %>
      <%= vpf.label :content, style: "display: block" %>
      <%= vpf.text_area :content %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*Create method of Post:*

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: "Post was successfully created." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

*Current new method of Post:*

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  Venue.all.each do |v|
    @post.venue_posts.new(venue: v)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you have a `has_many :venues, through: :venue_posts` then you can just `@post.venues << v` and be done with it. Super simple!

Comment: Okay, thank you, but will that still work with the accepts_nested_attributes_for (meaning will I be able to show forms for all the VenuePosts when creating a Post)?

Comment: If you have something that accepts nested attributes it's even easier, you just `Post.new(post_params)` where `post_params` encapsulates the [Rails parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) for that type of record.

Comment: Okay, but I still need some model reference for that though if I want to use fields_for in my form though, right?

Comment: True, but in a `through` situation it's taken care of for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `<<` causes the record to save, this is at least implied by the [Documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Instead to instantiate a `Post` for each `Venue` you should be able to make the following adjustments

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :venue_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :venues, through: :venue_posts
end

class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :venue_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :venue_posts
end
```

And in the Controller Action

```
def new
  Venue.all.each {|v| v.posts.build}
end
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, but will that still work with the accepts_nested_attributes_for (meaning will I be able to show forms for all the VenuePosts when creating a Post)?

Answer (score 1):

[`<<`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C) method does save new records, it's a little subtle in the explanation:

> Adds one or more records to the collection by setting their foreign keys to the association’s primary key. Since `<<` flattens its argument list and **inserts each record**, push and concat behave identically. Returns self so several appends may be chained together.

Maybe this makes it a little clearer:

```rb
post = Post.new  #=> #<Post:0x00007fdbc7279610 id: nil>
venue_post = post.venue_posts.build(venue: Venue.first)
venue_post.post  #=> #<Post:0x00007fdbc7279610 id: nil>

# when you save venue_post the new post is also saved
venue_post.save
#=>
# TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
# Post Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
# VenuePost Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "venue_posts" ("venue_id", "post_id") VALUES (?, ?) RETURNING "id"  [["venue_id", 1], ["post_id", 5]]
# TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  commit transaction
```

which is what happens when you use `<<` but for all the venue_posts.

As far as I can tell you don't need `v.venue_posts << vp` part at all, since you're just building new records for your form, and you really want to use `has_many through:` association here:
*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association*

Comment: Okay, thank you, but will that still work with the accepts_nested_attributes_for (meaning will I be able to show forms for all the VenuePosts when creating a Post)?

Comment: adding `through:` association is optional it just adds shortcut methods and does the joins for you like `Venue.first.posts` or `Post.first.venues`. you can still use `has_many :venue_posts` association with nested attributes if that's what you need. and you do need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :venue_posts` if you have extra fields in your form for venue_posts as in `f.fields_for :venue_posts do |ff|`. you didn't include your form in the question so I focused only on *"Object being created for no reason"* part.

Comment: Okay, the fields for part is what I already use right now, so that’s great! Will try it out later, thank you!